# How to insert values with out scientific notation in ssis package creation?

Tags: sql, database, ssis

I developing package for import data from excel to SQL DB using SSIS.

In one of the excel sheet following value present no format is used it's general .

```
0.0000316    
0.0000088   
0.0000022    
0.000001
```

I insert above value into DB following data present in DB. in DB it's float data type.

```
3.16E-05
8.8E-06
2.2E-06
1E-06
```

How to insert without E . I need to insert same value in excel sheet. It's possible?

Answer (score 2):

The data in the database is exactly the same data in the Excel. The only difference is the way in which it's shown. I don't know what are you using that data for, but I can assure you that you'll get the same data when fyou do calculations as you would in Excel (Excel also uses flotaing point numbers).

If you need, for some reason, to see the query results in a particular format, use SQL Server [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function.

Comment: i understand both are same. but i need value present in DB. I'm doing some calculation with that value. No issues arrive due to this...?

Comment: you are answering yourself: "I understand both are the same". If so, what could be the difference in your calculations? Another question is the comparison of a floating point with an exact numeric type (like SQL Server numeric, or C# decimal). But Excel also uses floating point numbers. In fact most computer calculations are doing using floating point: it's strange to find exact numeric types: they are used for some very specific things like bank acounts, billing, accounting, where a difference of one cent in a very big amount is inadmissible